# How to show numeric input modal view like on iPad's lock screen?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

when I unlock my iPad I get a small modal view where I can enter a PIN. I'd like to use the same thing within my app to protect a sensitive setting with a PIN.

Which UI element is used here? How can I fire it up?

Thanks.

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm i dont think that view it available to use use by default, but you can build your own you can use the following code to get the numeric pad

```
UITextField tf;
                        tf.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
```

or you can create a custom keyboard with interface builder you just need 12 buttons ans 4 text boxes then do it programmatically pretty straightforward hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Indeed, I ended up building my own and then using PresentModalViewController() to show it. Afterwards I adjust size and position because it would otherwise always be shown in PageFormSheet's default size.

Comment: @krumelur:- can you share how did you achieve this

Comment: I can't give you the code. It's company property but I can give you the basics. Either use IB or code to generate a view which has the butons 0..9, a cancel button and a "back" button. Also add four input fields with masked characters. Atach handlers to all buttons. Whenever a button is touched, update the 1st, 2nd, ... textfield. If counter reaches 4, dismiss the modal dialog and fire a callback to inform the user. The caller then has to check/remember the PIN, reopen the PIN input and ask for confirmation. It's all basic handmade development.

Comment: You get the black effects of the buttons by adding a background image and by applying shadows:
this.oBtn0.SetBackgroundImage ( UIImage.FromFile ( "Data/Images/buttonbackground.png" ), UIControlState.Normal );
   this.oBtn1.SetBackgroundImage ( this.oBtn0.BackgroundImageForState(UIControlState.Normal), UIControlState.Normal );

this.oBtn0.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
   this.oBtn0.Layer.ShadowOffset = new System.Drawing.SizeF(3, 3);
   this.oBtn0.Layer.ShadowRadius = 3.0f;
   this.oBtn0.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;